# htaccess block all query string but not index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a site that is being attacked all the time and it is using `joomla extensions`

So I am trying to figure out what exploit are they using and I have decided to block those

I am using the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)xqgu=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fck=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

but its not working as I can still access the site on

```
site.com/index.php?fck=you
```

Can I block all get request that have paramer after index.php?=

that are not coming form my IP?

like

```
site.com/index.php?fck=uxsw
site.com/index.php?xqgu=otzd
site.com/index.php?some=thing
```

buy allow get on

```
site.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

or

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx yy.yy.yy.yy
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: Can you explain how/why the answer will solve the problem in question, that will add value to your answer rather than posting the code-only answer.